# getDataIDs() of jqGrid returning empty array even though there is data in the grid

Tags: jqgrid

```php
//JavaScript deferred load in main.php

var lista = jQuery("#list").getDataIDs();
console.log(lista);
-------------------------------

//getdata.php
$responce = new stdClass;

$responce->page = $page;
$responce->total = $total_pages;
$responce->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row['slidescol'];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row['torder'],$row['title'],$row['iconpath'],$row['bannerurl'],$row['summary'],$row['headerstitle'],$row['headers'],$row['backurl'],$row['forwardurl'],$row['thisurl'],$row['slidescol']);
    $i++;
}        

fclose($handle);
echo json_encode($responce);
```

I am trying to determine why my `console.log` is returning a blank array or empty set even though there are four rows in the grid.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which you posed don't show exactly where in *JavaScript your code* will be called the method `getDataIDs`. I suppose that you call it in the wrong place. Initially one place on the page empty `<table id="list"></table>`, then you should *create* the grid with respect of `$("#list").jqGrid({/*options*/})`. You can use `getDataIDs` only on the grid which is created and not on empty `<table>` element. Typically one uses `getDataIDs` inside of `loadComplete` callback because in the place one can be sure that the grid is created and the data are filled in the body of jqGrid.

Comment: I must send a big thank you for this reply. Everything is working much nicer now inside of loadcomplete.

Comment: Oleg, I called getDataIDs inside loadComplete and it returned an empty array. What gives? The grid is full of data so it IS loaded....

Comment: @sarsnake: You should post more full description what you do and what you *need to do*. I mean that one need to see JavaScript code and the test data used for the input. Moreover usage of `getDataIDs` is really needed **very seldom**. In the most cases one try to use `getDataIDs` instead of usage more effective other possibilities of jqGrid like `cellattr`, `rowattr`, `beforeSelectRow`, `beforeProcessing` and so on. So it's better that you should describe the problem which you try to solve and not just to understand why `getDataIDs` works not like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```
...

loadComplete: function() {

    var ids = $(this).jqGrid('getDataIDs');

    // i'm expanding all the sub grids here, but can do anything with the array
    var len = ids.length;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        $(this).jqGrid('expandSubGridRow', ids[i]);
    }

}
```